# Given a n x m matrix in a file, how to read every a'th line in the first column?

Tags: python

(this question refers to Python)

So, my question might seem a bit involved, but it's conceptually not that tricky (I hope).

I've basically tried millions of different solutions but can't get it to work.

So, my issue is that I have a grid of 4D coordinates x1, x2, x3, x4; listed row by row in a matrix for which the 5th entry in each row is the value of a function that takes these four coordinates as arguments. So, it looks like

[ x1 x2 x3 x4 func(x1,x2,x3,x4)] (yes, delimited by a space, ' ')

Since the x's live on a grid with a certain size (I have size = 21), we get a very large matrix, where for each fixed triplet of x1, x2 and x3 (for example), the coordinate x4 is running through size (21) values, with a corresponding func in each row being the output of that particular set of coordinates.

Here is what I need help with:

When reading this humonguous file into another program, I wish to read the x1's into their own separate list (of size = 21), and the x2's into their own list and so forth. But to avoid repetition of reading the same value for the coordinates over and over again, I only need to read every a'th row, where a is some number as explained below.

So, for the coordinate x4, I need to read the first 21 entries of column 4, for coordinate x3 I need to read the value in the third column every 21st row, for x2 the second column in every 21*21'st row, and then the same for x1 (with an even larger interval).

What is the best way to do this?

(I will refrain from posting my failed attempts since I don't want to clog up this post, but I can share them if you need them for understanding or to laugh at me :-)

I can't tell you how much I'd appreciate some help with this!

PS.

The matrix looks something like (the actual numerical values of the coordinates are messier than this, but hopefully serves to give you an idea):

```
row 0: -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 func(-1,-1,-1,-1)

row 1: -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -0.95 func(-1,-1,-1,-0.95)

row 21: -1.0 -1.0 -0.95 -1 func(-1,-1,-0.95,-1)

row 22: -1.0 -1.0 -0.95 -0.95 func(-1,-1,-0.95,-0.95)
```

etc...

Edit:
Hi! Sorry if I wasn't specific enough in my OP. I think I managed to solve the issue though, at least it seems to work for now:

```
size = 21 length = size**4 a= [] b= [] c= [] d= [] func= []

f = open('file.dat','r') lines = f.readlines() for x in lines:
    a.append(float(x.split(' ')[0]))
    b.append(float(x.split(' ')[1]))
    c.append(float(x.split(' ')[2]))
    d.append(float(x.split(' ')[3]))
    func.append(float(x.split(' ')[4]))   f.close() a = sorted(list(set(a))) b = sorted(list(set(b))) c = sorted(list(set(c))) d = sorted(list(set(d)))
```

Comment: What format is the input, a text file? Also, I really recommend you change `21` to `2` and post a complete sample input (using toy values), it should only be 16-by-4 if I've understood correctly. Also are you using any other packages like numpy or pandas?

Comment: In arrays in python, you can index using a "skip" value: `l[0::2]`. This says to look at every second value

Comment: Please include any packages/libraries you are using  as tags :D

Comment: Hi! Sorry if I wasn't specific enough in my OP. I think I managed to solve the issue though, at least it seems to work for now:
'size = 21
length = size**4

a= []
b= []
c= []
c= []
func= []

f = open('file.dat','r')
lines = f.readlines()
for x in lines:
    a.append(float(x.split(' ')[0]))
    b.append(float(x.split(' ')[1]))
    c.append(float(x.split(' ')[2]))
    d.append(float(x.split(' ')[3]))
    func.append(float(x.split(' ')[4]))
f.close()

a = sorted(list(set(a)))
b = sorted(list(set(b)))
c = sorted(list(set(c)))
d = sorted(list(set(d)))'

Comment: PS. I'm not sure how formatting works on this forum (yes, I am new here). My comment seems to be posted unedited, while I marked the code part with ' ' as I think I should have done? Sorry if you can't read it :P

Comment: Don't post new info in the comments, you can just edit your OP and format it nicely there

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```py
from pathlib import Path

n = 2
columns = 4
result = [set() for _ in range(columns)]

with Path("file.dat").open as file:
for line_number in range(n ** columns):
    line = file.readline().split()
    for column in range(columns):
        result[column].add(float(line[column]))

result = [sorted(list(line)) for line in result]
```